# Tasks settings of asp.net core project with typescript

Tags: typescript, angular, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, asp.net-core-1.0

I have asp.net core app with typescript and angular2 being developed in VS2015.
I'm trying to move it to vscode.
I've created new project with dotnet command and started setting up dependencies, tools, etc.
I set up task for debugging .net core app (it was created by vs code)
Now I'm looking at how do I set up building typescript in watch mode and run gulp tasks.
VS code has offered me earlier to create command for TS, but as I understand, there can be only 1 command! So how do I get asp.core app running with debugging alongside with TS compilation, tslint processing and gulp tasks in vscode in most correct way with output to vscode from all those tools?

tasks for typescript:

```
{
// See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
// for the documentation about the tasks.json format
"version": "0.1.0",
"command": "tsc",
"isShellCommand": true,
"args": ["-w", "-p", "."],
"showOutput": "silent",
"isWatching": true,
"problemMatcher": "$tsc-watch"
}
```

tasks for dotnet:

```
{
// See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
// for the documentation about the tasks.json format
"version": "0.1.0",
"command": "dotnet",
"isShellCommand": true,
"args": [],
"tasks": [
    {
        "taskName": "build",
        "args": [ ],
        "isBuildCommand": true,
        "showOutput": "silent",
        "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
    }
]
}
```

Comment: You should add the [asp.net-core] tag as well.  That way your question will show up when someone searches for asp.net core.  With just the [asp.net-core-1.0] tag your question only shows up when people include 1.0 in their search.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to run multiple tasks at the same time.  I would recommend looking into npm scripts.

npm allows you to create commands in your packages.config file.  Here is an example that I use in my projects.  Check out the "start" command.  It will use a package called "concurrently" to run multiple commands at the same time.  In this case it is running tsc:w which is defined in another command below, running lite server, and running my gulp task.

I hit debug in VSCode, and in the VSCode terminal (CTRL + ~) and run npm start, and I'm good to go.

packages.config

```
{
  "name": "queuedodge-site",
  "description": "web front end for queue dodge.",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "install": "tsc && gulp sass && gulp bundle",
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" \"gulp default\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings",
    "bundle": "gulp default"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "systemjs": "^0.19.27",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.6",
    "es6-promise": "3.1.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "jquery": "2.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "typings": "1.0.4",
    "systemjs-builder": "0.15.16",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "gulp": "3.9.1",
    "gulp-sass": "2.2.0",
    "gulp-markdown": "1.2.0",
    "tslint": "3.5.0",
    "yargs": "4.7.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, this is possible. But not looking like a best of choices.

Comment: I was looking for the same thing and also trying to avoid node/npm as that would defeat the purpose of having dotnet serve the project.

In the end i settled for using webpack to do serve/compile/package ... and other stuff.

Something like: https://gist.github.com/scottaddie/ec61dcedb47ff9113bf3#file-tasks-json

Then run the tasks from VS Code command pallete